# Django - multiple queries with pagination

Tags: django, django-queryset

After updating from Django 1.9 to 3.2.5 my advanced search function doesn't work with pagination anymore.

I have two search functions. One which is always available in the header to search for project names and is included in my base.html template. The other one is an advanced search function which allows to search for specific criterias e.g. department, project name, status, etc.

all works fine as long as there is no pagination. the normal search function works with pagination but the advanced doesn't.

The problem seems the return of the query, which returns one list for mutliple queries starting with q=['','','']. Because my form fields in my advanced search have different names e.g. qD,qS, etc. the parts of the list can't be properly assigned.

url return when doing advanced search before changing page:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/advanced_search/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=rzIvrOJdUMHwwxaSR18hy48mPTNCORXjaMYigqELXKRlKzNhBpEjbVSueQGHs7yl&qD=corporate&qC=&qN=&qT=&qS=&qA=&qCD=
```

url return when doing advanced search after changing page:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/advanced_search/?page=2&q=(None,%20%27corporate%27,%20%27%27,%20%27%27,%20%27%27,%20%27%27,%20%27%27,%20%27%27)
```

here my django and html code:

views.py

```
# normal search
def search(request):
    template = 'MAR_Projects/projects.html'
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    if query:    
        filtered_projects = table_projects.objects.filter(Q(Project_Code__icontains=query) | Q(Project_Name__icontains=query))
    else:
        filtered_projects = table_projects.objects.all().order_by('-Project_Creation')
        
    searchResultCount = filtered_projects.count   
    pages = pagination(request, filtered_projects)
    context = {'items': pages[0],
               'page_range': pages[1],
               'query': query,
               'searchResultCount':searchResultCount
               }
    
    return render(request, template, context)

#advanced search
def advanced_search(request):
    template = 'MAR_Projects/advanced_search.html'
    filtered_projects = table_projects.objects.all()
    query = (request.GET.get('q'),request.GET.get('qD'), request.GET.get('qC'), request.GET.get('qN'), request.GET.get('qT'), request.GET.get('qS'), request.GET.get('qA'),
             request.GET.get('qCD'))
    result = False
    for i,q in enumerate(query):
        if q and i== 1:    
            filtered_projects = filtered_projects.filter(Q(Project_Department_id__BUs_Code__icontains = query[i]))
            result = True
        elif q and i== 2:    
            filtered_projects = filtered_projects.filter(Q(Project_Code__icontains = query[i]))
            result = True
        elif q and i== 3:    
            filtered_projects = filtered_projects.filter(Q(Project_Name__icontains = query[i]))
            result = True
        elif q and i== 4:    
            filtered_projects = filtered_projects.filter(Q(Project_Type_id__ProjectType_Code__icontains = query[i]))
            result = True
        elif q and i== 5:    
            filtered_projects = filtered_projects.filter(Q(Project_Status_id__ProjectStatus_code__icontains = query[i]))
            result = True
        elif q and i== 6:    
            filtered_projects = filtered_projects.filter(Q(Project_Assignee_id__Assignee_Name__icontains = query[i]))
            result = True
        elif q and i== 7:    
            filtered_projects = filtered_projects.filter(Q(Project_Creation__icontains = query[i]))
            result = True            
  
    searchResultCount = filtered_projects.count
    pages = pagination(request, filtered_projects)
    context = {'items': pages[0],
               'page_range': pages[1],
               'result': result,
               'query': query,
               'searchResultCount':searchResultCount,
               }
    
    return render(request, template, context)
```

advanced_search.html template

```
{% extends 'Mar_Projects/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<h4>Advanced search</h4>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">BUs</th>
      <th scope="col">Project Code</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Type</th>
      <th scope="col">Status</th>
      <!-- <th scope="col-sm">Description</th>-->
      <th scope="col">Assignee</th>
      <th scope="col">Creation Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <form method="get" action={% url 'MAR_Projects:advanced_search' %}>
    {% csrf_token %}
      <th scope="row"></th>
      <td><input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Department" aria-label="Department" name='qD' value= {{ request.GET.qD}}></td>
      <td><input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Code" aria-label="Code" name='qC' value= {{ request.GET.qC}}></td>
      <td><input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Name" aria-label="Name" name='qN' value= {{ request.GET.qN}}></td>
      <td><input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Type" aria-label="Type" name='qT' value= {{ request.GET.qT}}></td>
      <td><input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Status" aria-label="Status" name='qS' value= {{ request.GET.qS}}></td>
      <td><input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Assignee" aria-label="Assignee" name='qA' value= {{ request.GET.qA}}></td>
      <td><input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Date" aria-label="Date" name='qCD' value= {{ request.GET.qCD}}></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>{%if result %}{{searchResultCount}} Found{% endif %}</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Search"></td>
    </tr>
    </form>
  
  
  
    {%if result %}
    {%for pj in items%}
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">{{ forloop.counter0 | add:items.start_index }}</th>
      <td>{{pj.Project_Department}}</td>
      <td><a href = '/projects/{{pj.Project_Id}}'>{{pj.Project_Code}}</a></td>
      <td>{{pj.Project_Name}}</td>
      <td>{{pj.Project_Type}}</td>
      <td>{{pj.Project_Status}}</td>
      <!--<td style="max-width:350px;white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden">{{pj.Project_Description}}</td>
      -->
      <td>{{pj.Project_Assignee}}</td>
      <td>{{pj.Project_Creation}}</td>
    </tr>
    {%endfor%}
  {% endif %}
  </tbody>
  
</table>
<br/>
{%if result %}
{% include 'MAR_Projects/pagination.html' %}
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

base.html template

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/open-iconic/1.1.1/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha256-BJ/G+e+y7bQdrYkS2RBTyNfBHpA9IuGaPmf9htub5MQ=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <title>{% block title%}Project{%endblock%}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{%url 'MAR_Projects:home' %}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{%url 'MAR_Projects:projects' %}">Projects Overview</a>
      </li>    
      
    
    <li class="nav-item">
    
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'MAR_Projects:projectCreate' %}">
            <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp; Project
        
        </a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" method="GET" action = {% url 'MAR_Projects:search-results' %}>
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name='q' value= {{ request.GET.q}}>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" href="{%url 'MAR_Projects:advanced_search' %}">Adv. Search</a>
    </li>    
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{ user }}</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="/profile">Profile</a>   
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="/logout">Logout</a>
        </div>
      </li>
  
    </ul>  
  </div>
  {% else %}
    <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
    </li> 
    </ul>  
  
   {% endif %}
    
</nav>
<br/>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    {% if messages %}
        <div class="span12">
        {% for message in messages %}
            <div class="alert alert-{{ message.level_tag }}" role="alert">
                {{ message|safe }}
            </div>
            
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
       {% block content %}
       {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

took me a while but I answer my own question.

it might not be the best solution but it works.

In the views.py:

```
query = (request.GET.get('q'),request.GET.get('qD'), request.GET.get('qC'), request.GET.get('qN'), request.GET.get('qT'), request.GET.get('qS'), request.GET.get('qA'),
         request.GET.get('qCD'))
qDic = {'q':query[0],'qD':query[1],'qC':query[2],'qN':query[3],'qT':query[4],'qS':query[5],'qA':query[6],'qCD':query[7]}
searchResultCount = filtered_projects.count
pages = pagination(request, filtered_projects)
context = {'items': pages[0],
           'page_range': pages[1],
           'result': result,
           'query': qDic,
           'searchResultCount':searchResultCount,
           }

return render(request, template, context)
```

I created a dictionary qDic and inserted my query results.

In my pagination.html template:

```
 {% if items.has_other_pages %}
<div class="col-6 offset-3 text-center pagination-set">
    <nav aria-label="">
        <ul class="pagination justify-content-end">
            {% if items.has_previous %}
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ items.previous_page_number }} {% if query %}&qD={{ query.qD }}&qC={{ query.qC }}&qN={{ query.qN }}&qT={{ query.qT }}&qS={{ query.qS }}&qA={{ query.qA }}&qCD={{ query.qCD }}{%endif%}">&laquo;</a></li>
            {% else %}
                <li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link"><span>&laquo;</span></a></li>
            {% endif %}
            {% for i in page_range %}
                {% if items.number == i %}
                    <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="#">{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                {% else %}
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}{% if query %}&qD={{ query.qD }}&qC={{ query.qC }}&qN={{ query.qN }}&qT={{ query.qT }}&qS={{ query.qS }}&qA={{ query.qA }}&qCD={{ query.qCD }}{%endif%}">{{ i }}</a></li>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% if items.has_next %}
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" aria-label="Next" href="?page={{ items.next_page_number }}{% if query %}&qD={{ query.qD }}&qC={{ query.qC }}&qN={{ query.qN }}&qT={{ query.qT }}&qS={{ query.qS }}&qA={{ query.qA }}&qCD={{ query.qCD }}{%endif%}">&raquo;</a></li>
            {% else %}
                <li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link"><span>&raquo;</span></a></li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
    </nav>
 </div>{% endif %}
```

I handed over the queried dictionary entries to the according query fields in my advanced_search.html template.

hope this makes sense.

better solutions are always welcome.